# Align my select option and my input search at center of my #menu div

Tags: html, css

I'm making a menu structure for mobile but I am not able to align in center my select option menu and my search input.

I'm trying with margin: 0 auto; but its not working, my select option and my search input are not getting to the center of my menu.

The #menu div have 300px of width, and I want that my select option menu and my input search have 226px of width and aligned at center of my #menu div but I'm not having sucess doing this.

Someone sees what is wrong here?

I have my example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/x5pb7mw4/1/

My html:

```
<section id="menu-container">   
    <nav id="menu">
        <select id="select_menu"> 
            <option value="menu"  selected="selected" name="menu">- Menu -</option> 
        </select>   
        <ul class="dropDownMenu">    
             <li id="search_container">
                <form id="search" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input name="s" type="text" size="40" placeholder="Search..." />
                <button type="submit" name="search"></button>
                </form>
            </li> 
        </ul>
    </nav>
</section>
```

My css:

```
*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:none;

}
body
{
    min-width:320px;    
}


#menu-container{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    float:left;
    z-index:7;
    float:left;
    background:brown;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;  
}

#menu{
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

#menu ul{list-style:none;}


#menu .dropDownMenu .item_menu{display:none;}

#select_menu{
    margin:11px auto;
    height:30px;
    width:226px; 
    background:#ccc;
    color:#2F3083;
}


#search_container{
    float:right;    
}

#search button[type="submit"] {
    background: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 22px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    right: 10px;
}



#search input[type="text"] {
    font-size:13px;
    background: brown;
    border:2px solid #000;
    text-indent: 0;
    width:226px;
    margin:0 auto 10px auto;
    padding: 6px 15px 6px 15px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    text-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3); 
    color:#ccc;
}
```

Comment: PS - You have `float: left;` twice in your `#menu-container` section, and your `z-index: 7;` is not doing anything, since you don't have a `position` declared.

Answer (score 2):

Just add `display:table` to your `#select_menu`

```
#select_menu{
    margin:11px auto;
    height:30px;
    width:226px; 
    background:#ccc;
    color:#2F3083;
    display: table;
}
```

And then add `width: 100%;` `text-align: center;` to your **#search_container**

```
#search_container{
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x5pb7mw4/4/)** here

remove below style and add `text-align:center` to `#menu`

```
#search_container{
    float:right;    
}
```

Comment: This is the most effective method.

Comment: Thanks @TylerH, hopefully it would resolve problem asked in this Question

Comment: @Ozzc, can you please verify and revert back if you need further assistance on it. Thanks

Comment: Do remember to close this question(by accepting the answer). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Add text-align: center; to your #menu